# Print iframe content in Internet Explorer w/o Print Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, printing

I am trying to find a solution to a specific problem of printing images in Internet Explorer (IE) browser. It is to initiate printing **without** showing a *print preview* or the *default print dialog*.

So far, I have been able to initiate printing without generating a print popup/modal window. This was achieved by using an invisible iFrame on the ASPX page and writing the image to it, and then printing the content of the iFrame. However, the print dialog is still being thrown by the browser.

Approaches tried :

1. Some sources suggested injecting a VBScript which replaces the default print functionality. This failed to work as intended.

   ```
   sub Print()
       OLECMDID_PRINT = 6
       OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2
       OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER = 1
       call WB.ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER,1)
   End Sub
   document.write &lt;object id='WB' width='0' height='0' classid='CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2' &gt;&lt;/object>
   ```
2. Trying to simulate an OK response, once the print dialog was shown also couldn't work as it is difficult to capture - when the dialog is triggered.

   ```
   var collapsePrintPreview = function () {
               var enter = jQuery.Event("keypress");
               enter.which = 13;
               enter.keycode = 13;
               $("input").trigger(enter);
           };

               window.onbeforeprint = collapsePrintPreview;
               window.onafterprint = collapsePrintPreview;
   ```

Is there a known methodology to print by suppressing the Print Dialog window from client side for IE browser? Any insights or solutions to the problem is much appreciated.

P.S. The target browser is IE 9 and above.

**UPDATE 1**

The VBScript code fails to work even when written verbatim in the  tag of my ASPX page (Tested in IE9). It is not able to suppress the Print Dialog at all!!

**UPDATE 2**

The entire VBScript is written under the HTML of an ASPX page that also contains JavaScript code.

Comment: Have you considered that this may not be considered a feature by your users? I know it'd irritate me (if I were in the habit of printing things out any more).

Comment: Well, as strange as it may sound, this is a feature explicitly demanded by a large group of users!

Comment: VB isn't going to work, as it's no longer supported (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn384057(v=vs.85).aspx).  Sadly, printing is not an area that's received a lot of attention in recent versions of the browser, partly for security reasons.  (Many actions that some want automated are considered things to be triggered only by the user and therefore not available for automation, especially by public websites.)  You may be able to use print templates (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa753281(v=vs.85).aspx), but it's likely to involve more than a little C++.